# BluebirdJS promise with jQuery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, bluebird

Using `Promise.resolve($.ajax(options))` as mentioned here http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.resolve.html is not working.

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function makeRequest(options) {

      return Promise.resolve($.ajax(options))
        .then(function(data) { return data; },
              function (error) { return error; });

}
```

When I call and url that returns an error (403 in this situation), and I add one more '.then', it always calls the fulfilled handler.

```
makeRequest(options).then(iAmBeingCalledWhenTheRequestFails, iAmNotBeingCalled);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
  return Promise.resolve($.ajax(options))
    .then(function(data) { return data; },
          function (error) { return error; });
```

That's effectively doing:

```
try {
  return $.ajax(options);
} catch (e){
  return e;
}
```

Promises have exception handling like regular synchronous code, when you `return` form an exception handler you recover from the error (like try catch). If you want to add an error handler *and* keep the chain in a rejected state - you need to `throw` the error.

Better yet, don't attach the error handler in this case to begin with.

```
 return Promise.resolve($.ajax(options)); // that's all folks!
```

Comment: "when you return form an exception handler you recover from the error (like try catch)". Thanks very much, I think I was missing the point with promises (one of those things you think you know but you actually don't).

Comment: @WalterMacambira that's ok - jQuery very famously [missed the point of promises themselves](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970).

Comment: isn't it bad for performance to `throw` just to repass the error?

Comment: @WalterMacambira exceptions should be extremely rare and for edge cases anyway (like the server returning an error) - so it should not be a concern anyway. You can also `return Promise.reject(err);` to do the same thing (since if you return a promise from a `then` handler the chain will assume its state) but honestly - it's not a big deal since exceptions should be extremely rare.

Comment: @WalterMacambira If you don't actually intend to do anything with the error, then there's no reason to catch it in the first place. That's what the end of Benjamin's post says.

Comment: @JLRishe I need to handle the error in the case (tell the user why things wen't wrong). In this specific case, I am looking for any error message on $xhr.responseJSON, if none, it 'returns' the default error message.

Comment: @WalterMacambira on the client side unless you're doing tens of thousands of `throw`s the performance shouldn't be a problem. Even then - measure it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, you're right, there is no need to care about it in a scenario where it is a rare thing. But thanks for giving me an alternative.